# Scaling an image in a scroller resizes the scroller when relative dimension are set to the scroller

Tags: image, apache-flex, dimension, scroller

I would like to position relatively a scroller in my application like below.
When I scale the image, I resize the scroller...

```
<s:Scroller width="50%" height="50%" >
  <s:Group>
   <mx:Image 
       id="img"
       source="sample.jpg"
       />
  </s:Group>
 </s:Scroller>
```

If I set absolute dimension to the scroller like below, it does not resize (behaviour I want)

```
 <s:Scroller width="400" height="400" >
  <s:Group>
   <mx:Image 
       id="img"
       source="sample.jpg"
       />
  </s:Group>
 </s:Scroller>
```

.. but my intention is to position the scroller relatively to other components.
Any explanations/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Group` doesn't have a size, so it gets a measured size and becomes whatever it's collective children's sizes are.  Then the `Scroller` has a `ScrollerLayout` which sizes the Scroller:  If it has an explicit width/height, it uses that, otherwise it uses it's content sizes.  Flex ignores percent sizing it seems.

Check out the [ScrollerLayout source](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/supportClasses/ScrollerLayout.as), at the `updateDisplayList` method.  It doesn't take into account the Scroller's percent sizes :/.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works (but only by setting the percents in the Scroller). For example:

```
<s:HGroup width="50%" height="50%">


<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" >
    <s:Group>
        <mx:Image 
            id="img"
            source="sample.jpg"
            />
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>

<s:Button label="Zoom+" click="{zoomPlus()}">
</s:Button>
</s:HGroup>
```